# Any way to add a class name from variable to the host element in Angular2 without wiping out the existing classes?

Tags: css, angular, themes

I have a class name in a variable and I want to add this to the host element of my Angular2 component but I can’t figure out the way to do this.

I can add a class with HostBinding if it’s a constant string. But variables don’t exists in the component at the time of HostBinding is initialized. At least I get “undefined” when I try.

Is there any way to add a class from a variable to the host element? Or perhaps set HostBinding in constructor after I can access the variables? Using ngClass would be perfect otherwise but I can’t apply it to the host element itself.

As a side note - I do this because I’m doing CSS-theming with host-context(.my-theme). If there is some other way to apply this main class to the Angular2 component, I’m really open to ideas. The theme name comes from a variable so it’s not a constant.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `@HostBinding` to just bind to the class:

```
@HostBinding('class') hostClass;
```

Then in your constructor or wherever you have access to that variable you can append it to the class:

```
if (!hostClass) {
    this.hostClass = classVar;
} else {
    this.hostClass = `${this.hostClass} ${classVar}`;
}
```